# ktfmtFix error: "error: expected token: 'context'; generated ( instead"

Tags: android, kotlin, lint, kotlin-context-receivers

When running lint on my project I get the following error:

```
error: expected token: 'context'; generated ( instead
```

The error points to this section of code where I'm using the `context` keyword for context receivers.

```
val viewEffectMap: MutableMap<KClass<out ViewEffect>, context(Context, View) (effect: ViewEffect) -> Unit> = mutableMapOf()
```

The code compiles and runs as I'd expect, it's only the ktfmtFix command that complains.